# how to pass multiple scope variables into custom directive in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass 2 scope variables from controller into a custom directive and having problem in accessing both of them.Model is same for the directive and controller.
 Here is the code:

Html:

```
<myDirective data="var1" item="var2"></myDirective>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.var1="abc";
$scope.var2="xyz";
```

Directive:

```
  app.directive('myDirective', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment         
            scope: {
                    var1: '='
                     var2:'='

                     },

            templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',

            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {


                    } 
        }
    });
```

TemplateUrl: myTemplate.html

```
 <div>{{var1}}</div>  // This works
 <div>{{var2}}</div>  // This doesn't works
```

Any idea how can I use both?

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in your code

```
<popover data="var1" item="var2"></popover>
```

JS

```
app.directive('popover', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E', //E = element, A = attribute, C = class, M = comment
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            item: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           console.log(scope.data, scope.item);
        } 
     }
});
```

Comment: Same problem here. The second variable seems to work just one way, I mean, sending the variable to the directive, but if you modify it, the changes doesn't go back to the main scope, it's null when you print it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your template to match the names declared in the DDO.

```
<myDirective var1="var1" var2="var2"></myDirective>
```

Avoid using `data` as an attribute name. That is a reserved prefix that is stripped during normalization. For more information on attribute normilization, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Normilization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization).